# Error trying to compile SQLCiper iOS project

Tags: ios, sqlcipher

I'm trying to use SQLCipher in my iOS Phonegap Application. I've already installed SQLCipher and it worked fine. I recently upgraded my hole environment to support iOS6 and added SQLCipher to my project and now I'm getting this error:

```
/bin/sh -c /Volumes/Work/workspace/ios/webappskeleton/webappskeleton/sqlcipher/build/sqlcipher.build/Release-iphoneos/amalgamation.build/Script-9069D08A0FCE185A0042E34C.sh
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin11.4.2
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin11.4.2
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details.
make: *** No rule to make target `sqlite3.c'.  Stop.
```

I'm new to objective-c. If you have any ideas about to solve this problem please let me know it.

My environment:

```
OSX 10.7.5
XCode 4.5.2
XCode Command Line Tools 4.5.2
```

EDIT:

```
Here's the content of config.log:

This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by sqlite configure 3.7.12.1, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.62.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --enable-tempstore=yes CC=/usr/bin/gcc CFLAGS=-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = new-host-2.home
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 11.4.2
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
4 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 4.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 114 tasks, 608 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 1.54, Mach factor: 2.44
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/libexec
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/local/bin
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/usr/bin
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/usr/local/bin
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/local/bin
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/sbin
PATH: /Users/nadir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
PATH: /Users/nadir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin
PATH: /Users/nadir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
PATH: /Users/nadir/.rvm/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/local/mysql/bin
PATH: /Volumes/Work/android-sdk-macosx/tools
PATH: /Volumes/Work/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools
PATH: /usr/X11/bin
PATH: /usr/local/git/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2131: checking build system type
configure:2149: result: i386-apple-darwin11.4.2
configure:2171: checking host system type
configure:2186: result: i386-apple-darwin11.4.2
configure:2256: checking for gcc
configure:2283: result: /usr/bin/gcc
configure:2521: checking for C compiler version
configure:2529: /usr/bin/gcc --version >&5
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2533: $? = 0
configure:2540: /usr/bin/gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~67/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~67/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
configure:2544: $? = 0
configure:2551: /usr/bin/gcc -V >&5
llvm-gcc-4.2: argument to `-V' is missing
configure:2555: $? = 1
configure:2578: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2600: /usr/bin/gcc -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2   conftest.c  >&5
ld: warning: building for iOS, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX: /usr/lib/libSystem.dylib
configure:2604: $? = 0
configure:2642: result: a.out
configure:2659: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:2669: ./a.out
./configure: line 2671: 43322 Segmentation fault: 11  ./$ac_file
configure:2673: $? = 139
configure:2682: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=i386-apple-darwin11.4.2
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=/usr/bin/gcc
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2'
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_TCLLIBDIR_set=
ac_cv_env_TCLLIBDIR_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=i386-apple-darwin11.4.2
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=/usr/bin/gcc

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ALLOWRELEASE=''
AR=''
AWK=''
BUILD_CC=''
BUILD_CFLAGS=''
BUILD_EXEEXT=''
CC='/usr/bin/gcc'
CFLAGS='-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2'
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
FGREP=''
GREP=''
HAVE_TCL=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OPT_FEATURE_FLAGS=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='sqlite'
PACKAGE_STRING='sqlite 3.7.12.1'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='sqlite'
PACKAGE_VERSION='3.7.12.1'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB=''
RELEASE=''
SED='/usr/bin/sed'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SQLITE_OS_OS2=''
SQLITE_OS_UNIX=''
SQLITE_OS_WIN=''
SQLITE_THREADSAFE=''
STRIP=''
TARGET_DEBUG=''
TARGET_EXEEXT=''
TARGET_HAVE_READLINE=''
TARGET_READLINE_INC=''
TARGET_READLINE_LIBS=''
TCLLIBDIR=''
TCLSH_CMD=''
TCL_BIN_DIR=''
TCL_INCLUDE_SPEC=''
TCL_LIBS=''
TCL_LIB_FILE=''
TCL_LIB_FLAG=''
TCL_LIB_SPEC=''
TCL_SRC_DIR=''
TCL_STUB_LIB_FILE=''
TCL_STUB_LIB_FLAG=''
TCL_STUB_LIB_SPEC=''
TCL_VERSION=''
TEMP_STORE=''
USE_AMALGAMATION=''
USE_GCOV=''
VERSION=''
VERSION_NUMBER=''
XTHREADCONNECT=''
ac_ct_CC='/usr/bin/gcc'
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='i386-apple-darwin11.4.2'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='i386'
build_os='darwin11.4.2'
build_vendor='apple'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='i386-apple-darwin11.4.2'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='i386'
host_os='darwin11.4.2'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
lt_ECHO='echo'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define PACKAGE_NAME "sqlite"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "sqlite"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.7.12.1"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "sqlite 3.7.12.1"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""

configure: exit 1
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: works fine when I call it from the console... sorry - no idea

Comment: We would need to see the contents of the config.log as it would contain the details of the error that occurred.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, the content of the config.log is in the message above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are facing the same problem, just remove this repository content: {projectname}.xcodeproj/xcuserdata

Thanks Daij-Djan & Nick Parker for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error.

I solved it by lowering the iOS Deployment Target from 6.1 to 5.0:

[image]